# Why isn't my javascript working in wordpress ( Did I link it the right way)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Here is the function.php

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function maxprofessional_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'maxprofessional-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), _S_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'maxprofessional-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'maxprofessional-javascript', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/app.js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-icons', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css' );


    wp_style_add_data( 'maxprofessional-style', 'rtl', 'replace' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'maxprofessional-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), _S_VERSION, true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'maxprofessional_scripts' );
```

Have I linked my javascript file correctly ? Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must register first:

`wp_register_script('app-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', false, '1.0', true);`

and then enqueue:

`wp_enqueue_script( 'app-js' );`

Comment: Is it not the same exact thing I typed ? @joseph

Comment: @HZDevs no it isn't... it has a `/` in front of `js/app.js`

Comment: i did that now , but for some reason it is still not working , must i use any script src on the page that i want to add it to ?

Comment: @HZDevs i think i see the problemn... you must register first, I changed the answer to show this

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use "/" before js directory

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'maxprofessional-javascript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js' );
```

Also It's good to use jquery as script dependency. Example

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'space-style', SPACE_CSS . '/master.css', null, SPACE_VERSION );

wp_enqueue_script( 'space-swiper-script', SPACE_JS  . '/swiper.min.js', ['jquery'], SPACE_VERSION, true );
```